# Data extraction from user defined attribute

Tags: vba

I need help to extract Image link from "data-src" attributes using VBA macro.

eg:-

I wrote a code but vba converts "element.data-src" to "element.Data - src". Hence it gives me an error message when i run the macro.

Somebody, can you please help me?

Code:-

```
Const Meta_TAG As String = "img"
Dim kwd3 As String

Set Doc = ie.document
Set metaElements = Doc.all.tags(Meta_TAG)

For Each element In metaElements
        MsgBox (element.Data - src)    //getting error on this line of code
Next
```

Comment: Need extract data-src from below image tag:-

Comment: <img alt="" data-src="content/logo.jpg"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim elements As Object, element As Object
Set elements = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")

For Each element In elements
    Debug.Print element.GetAttribute("data-src")  '.innerText
Next
```

Comment: Don't think you need the innerText here

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, indeed not needed.